# Why am I getting a NZEC error in my code.

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am solving a coding question in python 2.7 and occurred a NZEC error code. I am not able to understand the reason to it. I know that NZEC generally occurs when you divide by zero or access an invalid position or variable.

```
import math
for t in xrange(int(raw_input())):
    n=raw_input()
    l=len(n) 
    ans=0
    for i in xrange(l):
        count=0
        for j in xrange(i+1,l):
            if int(n[j])<int(n[i]):
                count+=1
        ans+=math.factorial(count)*count
    print ans+1
```

Comment: I do get a `0` error code if in the first `raw_input` I enter `0` (thus the loop doesn't run, and the program is finished properly). What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Perhaps is there an element of `n` that is not a digit?

Comment: no its just the digits.

Comment: i just mean if my logic is wrong according to the question i am solving then WA is valid but i am getting a NZEC code. So it just got me thinking about the reason it may be. I may be missing something in my concept then.

Comment: where is link to coding question ?

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/problems/NEXTNUM    avoid telling me the correct logic.

Comment: Maybe I found some clue in FAQ on this page - sometimes data can have extra space at the end. And this space can give exception because it can't be converted to `int()`. See: https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7593/why-do-i-get-an-nzec/60004

Comment: for a matter of fact it worked. I just added .strip() when i took the input and it didnt gave me NZEC this time. thanks. P.S. i got a WA though.